# Switching Long-Standing Thunderbird POP Account to IMAP... What Happens to Current Folders (Inbox, Drafts, Trash, Folders I Created, etc.)?

Tags: switch

Is there any comprehensive guide for switching safely from POP to IMAP in Thunderbird and customizing how messages and folders are migrated to new IMAP server folders, maintaining folder nesting structure, and determining what stays local??  After reading MANY "Similar questions", I'm more unsure (afraid) than ever about trying to make this switch without either losing anything or altering folder structure.
Also, currently I back up my entire Thunderbird profile folder 6 times a day - certainly millions of messages in total, since I save pretty much all of my received messages since 1994 when I established my current POP e-mail account/address.  Is there any way to back up the contents of the new IMAP folders too once I make the switch?

Comment: You should backup your emails as you have been downloading them from the server, unless you kept them on the server, unclear if that’s the case or not. Should be as simple as, creating a new Thunderbird profile, and then importing your existing MBOX file

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand(?).  Yes, in my current POP account It's set to download messages and delete them from the server.  I was under the assumption (PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong!) that with IMAP... the InBox is ACTUALLY the LIVE SERVER CONTENTS, not a downloaded copy of the server's contents.  And I guess that the other standard folders (Drafts, Templates, Sent, and I'm not sure about Archives) are ALSO technically on the server, just in a different limited storage location which I CANNOT access without being on the Internet... is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Mozilla article
[Switch from POP to IMAP account](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/switch-pop-imap-account).

In short, you need to disable your POP account and create a new
IMAP account. This would leave you with everything that you had
for the POP account.

If you wish to transfer the previous stuff from the POP account to the
IMAP account, move messages by dragging and dropping.
This might also work for entire sub-folders, but the article doesn't
promise that.

You may use the Local Folders account to store your
old emails, instead of moving them to the IMAP server.

Comment: Thanks very much for the great article!  I'm just about ready to try this.  Just wondering, can Thunderbird automatically share/sync the address book?  If not, what's the best way to copy it manually and keep it updated?  Thanks again!

Comment: There are various methods for the address book. See and choose a method from [link1](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1340955#answer-1422340) and [link2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1130592#answer-898788).